# Reading same matches of using regex and storing in csv in multiple line

Tags: python, python-re

### I have a txt file :

```
Your Name: Arya Arjun
Subject Name :
    Math

Your Name: Arya Arvind
Subject Name :
    Science
```

---

### I am using a regex to get the name :  ^Your Name:[\S]*(.*)

Code :

```
filename = "Path/File.txt"
fo = open(filename, 'r')
lines = fo.readlines()

name = ""
for line in lines:
    match = re.findall("^Your Name:[\S]*(.*)", line)

    if len(match) > 0:
        name += ",".join(match)
print("-----------Your Name------------")
print("name :",name)
```

---

### O/P >
name : Arya Arjun Arya Arvind

so Its storing the name in csv like  below.

---

### Now I'm storing the result(names) in a csv file but its storing like this :

### [image]

I need to save it like this:

### [image]

Please let me know if any updates.

Comment: Do you want to reduce the length of the name(s) to a max of 5?

Comment: Please, show the code you're using to write file.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for line in lines:
>     match = re.findall("^Your Name:[\S]*(.*)", line)
>
> if len(match) > 0:
>     name += ",".join(match)
> ```

That's just weird. Where did you copy-n-paste that from?

Your example inputs suggest that
matching zero-or-more non-space characters
will always boil down
to "we match zero such characters".
So delete that.
And replace it with `\s+` to skip the
(approximately one?) SPACE characters
after the `:` colon.

Notice that no `,` comma characters
appear in the output. So the `.findall()`
is pointless, and it distracts maintainers
of this code. Say what you mean and mean
what you say. Replace it with a
simple `.search()`.

The `name` identifier is poorly chosen,
since it apparently is supposed to
accumulate all names found in the file.

The `len(match)` check seems to invite
a "'NoneType' has no len()" diagnostic.

Putting all of these together gives us:

```
names = []
for line in lines:
    match = re.search(r'^Your Name:\s+(.*)', line)

    if match:
        names.append(match.group(1))

print(','.join(names))
```

or if you prefer use `'\n'.join(names)` to put them on seperate lines.

---

The regular expression is a terrific tool.
But this problem is simple enough
that you might prefer to stick
with simple string manipulation.

```
    your_name = 'Your Name: '
    if line.startswith(your_name):
        name = line.removeprefix(your_name)
        names.append(name)
```